# HTML - JS How to open an image in an image popup by clicking on it?

Tags: html, image, popup

I should write some code in `html` or `javascript` or other to open a popup window by clicking on an image. 
I have already seen the `window.open()` method, but this isn't what I am looking for.
Precisely I want to open an image popup like Twitter does: overshadowing the background and displaying the image enlarged in the middle of the screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a lightbox to do it.

There is a simple example in this link:

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

It's really simple to use. Include the script tags and CSS stylesheets in your HTML file, and then simply use:

```
<a class="example-image-link" href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-1"><img class="example-image" src="images/thumb-1.jpg" alt="Girl looking out people on beach"></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

A very simple way to popup a image when click on click here text.

```
<a href="" onclick="window.open('img.png','targetWindow', 'toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=1090px, height=550px, top=25px left=120px'); return false;">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<img id="myImg" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> More :https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap, else, make a DIV with position absolute/fixed and centered. On click get the URL of image and put this inside the new DIV in a img tag. Finally Add a fadeIn/Out to the new DIV for the effect.