# Open Image in pop up from an array of Images

Tags: javascript, css, image, jsp

I am loading images from a database and following instructions given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954980/html-js-how-to-open-an-image-in-an-image-popup-by-clicking-on-it) question and referenced [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp). But this only pops up the first image in the array. The rest of the images do not pop up.
I have this Array that gives me the image on index 5

```
  ArrayList all = Customer.getCustomerImagesArray(custId);
     int size = all.size();

              <%
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    ArrayList one = (ArrayList) all.get(i);
                    String imgcode = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + (String) one.get(5);
                    session.setAttribute("docimage", imgcode);
              %>
               <form name="form1" id="form1" action="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=doverDoc" method="post">
                <tr style="height:20px; padding:2px;"> 
                <td><div align="center"><img id="myImg" src="${docimage}" width="80" height="80" alt="<%=(String) one.get(2)%>"></div></td>      
                </tr>
              </form>
            <% }%>
```

**EDIT**
Here is the Css:

```
<style>
            /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
            #myImg {
                border-radius: 5px;
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }

            #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

            /* The Modal (background) */
            .modal {
                display: none; /* Hidden by default */
                position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
                z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
                padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%; /* Full width */
                height: 100%; /* Full height */
                overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
                background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
            }

            /* Modal Content (Image) */
            .modal-content {
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 80%;
                max-width: 700px;
            }

            /* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
            #caption {
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 80%;
                max-width: 700px;
                text-align: center;
                color: #ccc;
                padding: 10px 0;
                height: 150px;
            }

            /* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
            .modal-content, #caption {
                animation-name: zoom;
                animation-duration: 0.6s;
            }

            @keyframes zoom {
                from {transform:scale(0)}
                to {transform:scale(1)}
            }

            /* The Close Button */
            .close {
                position: absolute;
                top: 15px;
                right: 35px;
                color: #f1f1f1;
                font-size: 40px;
                font-weight: bold;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }

            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
                color: #bbb;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
            @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
                .modal-content {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            } 
        </style>
```

and the javascript:

```
 <script>
                // Get the modal
                var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

                // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
                var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
                var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
                var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
                img.onclick = function () {
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                    modalImg.src = this.src;
                    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                }

                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function () {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            </script>
```

Div:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                <div id="caption"></div>
            </div>
```

How do I apply this popup effect on the other images? With this only the first image pops up.

Comment: this is likely not a JSP question at all. Please click edit, then `[<>] `snippet editor and create a [mcve] using HTML, CSS  and JavaScript only

Comment: the likely issue is you have duplicate IDs. IDs need to be unique. But you have not posted the code that pops the image here so it is not clear